# Reverse ball movement / set edges

Tags: javascript

I am stuck with the task. I am new to the coding world and not sure if these kind of questions are ok to ask. Any help will be appreciated. Tips on what function should I learn etc.

Need to write the function that will set boarders to the moving ball and also reverse it's movement. I have just managed to move it forward so far ...

```
<script>
  var velocityX = 15;
  var velocityY = 10;
  var positionX = 0;
  var positionY = 0;
  var direction = 0;
  var pos = 0;
  var ball = document.getElementById("ball");

  // YOUR CODE

  function myFunction() {
    if (direction) {
      pos -= 20;
      ball.style.left = pos + "px";
    } else {
      pos += 20;
      ball.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
  }

  //moves my ball each 1 msc as I put in time = 1
  setInterval(myFunction, 50);
</script>
```

Comment: Set some boundaries and then use an if to see if the next position will take it outside the boundaries?

Comment: Will try. Thanks.

Comment: It's always better to try something first, and then ask showing that effort

Comment: Got you. Will do next time

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the checking condition into your function, to check if your ball went beyond the boundaries. If yes - change the direction.

Comment: Thanks. Will check what 'checking condition' is

Comment: pos += 20;
if (pos > right_border) {
   direction = "left";
}

it's an example of checking condition

Answer (score 0):

You need to add boundaries and check them in the interval function. See the snippet below.

```js
var velocityX = 15;
var velocityY = 10;
var positionX = 0;
var positionY = 0;
var maxX = 300;
var minX = 0;

var direction = 0;
var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
ball.style.left = positionX + "px";

// YOUR CODE

function myFunction() {
  if (direction) {
    positionX -= velocityX;
    ball.style.left = positionX + "px";
    if (positionX <= minX) direction = 0;
  } else {
    positionX += velocityX;
    ball.style.left = positionX + "px";
    if (positionX >= maxX) direction = 1;
  }
}

//moves my ball each 1 msc as I put in time = 1
setInterval(myFunction, 50);
```

```css
#ball {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="ball"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked. Will try to understand what each lines does now. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Maya_Zhl is there a specific part you need assistance with?

Comment: See information about conditionals here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals